# How to resolve X11 event type originating in root window in Vala?

Tags: vala

I am trying to resolve the type of an event originating in the X11 root window from a Vala GTK application.

The problem I'm having is that I can only ever see `GDK_NOTHING` for the `to_string` conversion or `-1` for the raw integer enum value, irrespective of the event that is triggered:

```
filtering event type=GDK_NOTHING(-1), GDK_NOTHING, GDK_NOTHING
filtering event type=GDK_NOTHING(-1), GDK_NOTHING, GDK_NOTHING
filtering event type=GDK_NOTHING(-1), GDK_NOTHING, GDK_NOTHING
```

Example program:

```
using Gtk;
using Gdk;
using X11;
using GLib;

public class App : Gtk.Application {
    public static int main(string[] args) {
        app = new App();
        app.register(null);

        var gdk_root = Gdk.get_default_root_window();
        gdk_root.set_events(Gdk.EventMask.ALL_EVENTS_MASK);

        gdk_root.add_filter((filter, event) => {
            stdout.printf("filtering event type=%s(%d), %s, %s\n",
                          event.type.to_string(),
                          event.type,
                          event.get_event_type().to_string(),
                          event.window_state.type.to_string());
            return Gdk.FilterReturn.CONTINUE;
        });

        return app.run(args);
    }

    private static App app;
}
```

What is the correct way to identify the type of an X11 root window event in Vala GTK?

Answer (score 0):

The `GDKEvent` event that the `add_filter` function returns is not useful since the event type is always `GDK_NOTHING` (`-1`). Fortunately, it also returns a `Gdk.XEvent xevent`, which is more suitable for my needs.  One minor hitch is that `Gdk.XEvent` is a very unhelpful empty class, however we can to cast it to the correct struct, which in my case is `X.Event`.  Here's an example:

```
gdk_root.add_filter((filter, event) => {
    X.Event xev = *((X.Event*) xevent);

    if (xev.type != X.EventType.ConfigureNotify) {
        stdout.printf("event type=%d '%s'\n", xev.type, xev.type.to_string());
        return Gdk.FilterReturn.CONTINUE;
    }

    stdout.printf("dnd event x=%d y=%d w=%d h=%d\n", xev.xconfigure.x,
                  xev.xconfigure.y, xev.xconfigure.width, xev.xconfigure.height);
    return Gdk.FilterReturn.CONTINUE;
}
```